# adding a or condition with criteria

Tags: hibernate

I want to add a or condition with

```
ecModifiedCompany.addEq("modifiedCompanyName", instance.getModifiedCompanyName())
```

Is there any way to get this?

```
EntitySearchCriteria ecModifiedCompany= new EntitySearchCriteria();
ecModifiedCompany.addEq("modifiedCompanyName", instance.getModifiedCompanyName());
ecModifiedCompany.addEq("technology",instance.getTechnology());
ecModifiedCompany.addNe("id", instance.getId());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, criteria has disjunction, you can use like this,

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
    .add(Restrictions.eq("Field", Value))
    .add(Restrictions.eq("Field",value)));
```